# Trying to get the full string of an address in RStudio, same process as the included python code

Tags: python, r, shiny, geopy

I have some python code that I am trying to recreate in R. I am having trouble finding a package that will help me in this process.

I have tried to use omsdata and ggmap, but I have not achieved the desired results

```py
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="specify_your_app_name_here")
location = geolocator.geocode("175 5th Avenue NYC")
print(location.address)
#Flatiron Building, 175, 5th Avenue, Flatiron, New York, NYC, New York, ...
```

I am trying to do exactly what is done in the python code, except in R.

Comment: These should be helpful https://github.com/hrbrmstr/nominatim https://www.r-bloggers.com/introducing-the-nominatim-geocoding-package/

Comment: Google geocode api: https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway